# How to resize an iTextSharp.text.Image size into my code?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am pretty new in **iText** nd **iTextSharp** (the C# version of iText) and I have the following problem.

I am inserting some jpg charts inside my PDF. These charts are rapresented by some jpg like this one:

[image]

I insert it into a table of my PDF in this way:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = null;

..........................................
..........................................
..........................................
 if (currentVuln.UrgencyRating > 0)
                {
                    img = ChartHelper.GetPdfChartV2((int)currentVuln.UrgencyRating * 10, _folderImages);
                    vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img) { Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER, BorderColor = new BaseColor(79, 129, 189), BorderWidth = 1, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 30, PaddingTop = 10 });
                }
```

And this is a section of the **GetPdfChartV2()** method in which I load a chart immage:

```
    public static iTextSharp.text.Image GetPdfChartV2(int percentage, string _folderImmages)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image chart = null;
        string folderImmages = _folderImmages;

        if (percentage == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (percentage == 10)
        {
            chart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(_folderImmages + "1.jpg");
        }

        else if (percentage == 20)
        {
            chart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(_folderImmages + "2.jpg");
        }
        ....................................................
        ....................................................
        ....................................................
        else if (percentage == 100)
        {
            chart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(_folderImmages + "10.jpg");
        }

        return chart;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the chart immage is too big for my PDF and I obtain this orrible result:

[image]

So I have the following 2 questions:

1) Can I resize the **iTextSharp.text.Image** size into my code or have I to do it with an image editor?
If is it possible where have I to do it? when I load the immage into **GetPdfChartV2()** by the lines as:

```
chart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(_folderImmages + "1.jpg");
```

or when I put the immage into my PDF table cell:

```
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(img) { Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER, BorderColor = new BaseColor(79, 129, 189), BorderWidth = 1, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 30, PaddingTop = 10 });
```

Can you help me to solve this issue?

2) Why when I see the previous chart immage on my Windows Photo Viewer (100% of the size) I see it much smaller or here in the StackOverflow page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different strategies for adding an `Image` to a `PdfPCell`. These strategies are explained in chapter 4 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book), and the [XMen example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=84) demonstrates all possible options. If you don't understand Java, you'll find the C# port of the examples of chapter 4 [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04).

You are using this:

```
// we wrap he image in a PdfPCell
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img[0]);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

As documented, this option doesn't scale the image (which is what you want). If you want to scale the image, you could use this:

```
// we wrap the image in a PdfPCell and let iText scale it
cell = new PdfPCell(img[1], true);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

By adding the boolean parameter `true`, you ask iText to scale the image.

Another option is to use `addCell()` like this:

```
// we add the image with addCell()
table.AddCell(img[2]);
```

This will also scale the image, but use the properties of the default cell. If you don't change these properties, there will be a padding of 2 user units.

You also have the option to use *composite mode*:

```
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(img[3]);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

This will make sure the image is scaled to fill 100 percent of the cell width, unless you change the width percentage of the image, for instance:

```
img[3].WidthPercentage = 50;
```

This line will make sure that the width of the image is 50% of the available width of the cell.

Finally, you can scale the image before adding it to the cell as explained in your own (incomplete) answer.

Out of 5 possible options, you picked the single option that doesn't scale the image ;-)

Comment: Tnx, now I will stydy your example

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself in this way:

```
chart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(_folderImmages + "1.jpg");
chart .ScalePercent(24f);
```

As better explainet here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Answer (score 1):

In Java,  I was able to resize an image in a cell with this approach:

```
    Image image = Image.getInstance(fileLocation);
    image.scalePercent((float)7.5);
    PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(image,false);
```